# Pywhatkit and auto-py-to-exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller

my problem is basically that made a script in python using pywhatkit, in the console, it works fine but then when i convert py into exe and try to send the message just see a cmd opening and closing immediately and nothing happens. I also put a debug in the application but nothing shows up

Comment: Most likely you code uses other files such as images or sound, you need to add them when creating your .exe file. It is under Additional files in auto-py-to-exe

Answer (score 1):

It happens because your `pywhatkit` dependency not added to the `.EXE` file.
You should open the `projectname.spec` file and edit the following lines:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
**from PyInstaller.utils.hooks.import collect_submodules**

block_cipher = None
**hidden_imports= collect_submodules('pywhatkit')**


a = Analysis(
    ['mine.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    **hiddenimports=hidden_imports,**
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='mine',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
```

After saving the file you should run this file like the previous file.

```
pyinstaller --onefile projectname.spec
```

like that you have to install all the dependencies.